# detect a quotation in a string

Tags: php, regex, apache, preg-match

I am using php and I am using regular expressions to try to detect a quotation.

I would like for it to find matches only if it finds a quotation in the string

```
HELLO
```

Shouldnt find any matches

```
"HELLO"
```

Should find a match

```
"HELLO
```

Still should find a match

Comment: Are you trying to match the whole string that contains a quote?

Comment: Should it match a quotation on either side? Should `HELLO"` match?

Comment: If you simply want to find a quotation mark, strpos will be considerably more efficient that using regexp.

Comment: The quotation can be anywhere i nthe string. it can be HE"LLO . Just needs to find it. I tried what Dan Grossman did but it didnt return any matches.

Comment: The code is correct, I tested it on all of your strings to be sure. There's not much simpler pattern than matching one literal character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regular expression is just the quote character.

```
echo preg_match('/"/', $string);
```

That will return 0 for `HELLO`, 1 for `"HELLO"` and 1 for `"HELLO`

Comment: Wrong.  it will return 0 for `HELLO`, 1 for `"HELLO"` and 1 for `"HELLO`

Comment: You're confusing `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`

Comment: Wrong. You do not know what I was thinking.

Comment: It was still the right answer to his question, whether the commentary had a small mistake or not. -1 means the answer is not useful. Stop trolling.

Comment: I only find *correct* information to be useful.  A -1 isn't the end of the world.  So you made a mistake, everyone does.  And then you fixed it!  That was good on your part.  Answer is now useful.  Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), which checks for any double-quote in $thestring:

`if(preg_match('"', $thestring)) { ... }`

But it may be faster to use the [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function instead:

`if(strpos($thestring, '"') !== false) { ... }`

The code inside the `if` statements will only be executed if a double-quote is found.  My code examples won't return which text was quoted, although you can certainly do that with a few changes.

Comment: You need to fix `if(strpos($thestring, '"'))`.  If the quotation mark is the first character, strpos will return `0`.  That line should be `if(strpos($thestring, '"') !== false)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that Stephen, I've updated my example accordingly.

Comment: +1 for correctness.  This is also way easier to read than a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"(.*?)(\n|\r|$|")`.

Example:

http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/2994/screenshot2z0.png

**EDIT**: from your comments I understand that you don't need this; what you need is Colin O'Dell's answer (namely the `strpos` function). Still, I'm leaving this here in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: @Colin O'Dell I think that visual examples (i.e. RegExr screenshots) are the best for figuring out regex stuff (like jsfiddle is for html/css/js stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Not so difficult, IMHO :)
I guess you are just trying to determine whether there is a quote in the given string or not, right? So then it can by done by

```
preg_match('/"/',$string)
```

or more efficiently by

```
strpos($string,'"') || $string == '"'
```

Comment: As Stephen noted in my example, for a string starting with a double-quote, strpos will return 0 which could be interpreted as boolean false without the === or !== operators.

Comment: @Craige even though it could lead to an error since `strpos('"', '"') === 0`.

Comment: @PJK better yet use `strpos($string,'"') !== false`

Comment: @Stephen - yes it could, however that is simply a matter of knowing how to use the function/language.

Answer (score 0):

```
["]*HELLO["]*
```

will match HELLO with or without quotes on either side.

Or you can use

```
"{0,1}HELLO"{0,1}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the same question as I am?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(trim($string, '"') !== $string)`

Or `(trim($string, '"\'') !== $string)` for quotation or single quote